# How do I compare IP addresses in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address

I am storing IP addresses in a mysql database, and I want to perform queries where I check to see if a particular IP address already exists in the database. I've read that it is recommended to store IP addresses as an INT in a mysql database. So here is what I'm doing:

```
$ip = '209.173.53.167'; // some random IP address
$ip_long = ip2long($ip); // convert IP address to integer

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM ip_addresses 
        WHERE ip='{$ip_long}'";
```

I perform a similar operation when storing IP addresses, ensuring that they are stored as INT's. But the problem is that my comparison in the `WHERE` clause doesn't appear to work. For some reason `WHERE ip='{$ip_long}'` doesn't work. I have performed tests that should definitely work, but the comparison always fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you print/dump the query and run it in command/phpmyadmin, does it return as expected? Are you sure the names are correct and there aren't any problems with your SQL connection/execution (that you haven't posted)

Comment: Careful... you should be using prepared/parameterized queries here.  Never concatenate data directly into a query, even if it seems safe to you now.  You might not know in what context your code will be used in the future.

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 addresses, when stored as 32-bit integers, need to be stored as unsigned integers. It's possible MySql has silently converted a too-large signed integer to its twos-complement negative.

You may want to inspect your table and double check your query for this.